# How do I configure hardware raid in a Poweredge 2850?

Tags: raid, configuration, dell-poweredge, hardware-raid, bios

I just bought a Dell Poweredge 2850 from Craigslist and for the most part I'm happy with it's $300 price-tag, but I cannot figure out where to configure the embedded hardware raid...

I've seen online you should hit `<CTRL-M>`, but while booting my box never says that. I have `<CTRL-A>` (I think) for an LSI Logic config, but that seems to just program SCSI and verify drives on my SCSI-A and SCSI-B. Anyone have a clue where this RAID config is?

Comment: Could you verify which, if any RAID controller is installed?  The `CTRL+M` combo is for the Dell PERC card's BIOS.  It is possible, as you mention LSI, that another, or no, card is installed.

Comment: Have you looked at the DELL website?  I'm sure they might have the procedure to do this.

Comment: It sounds like the server doesn't have a RAID controller.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that you bought it with a PERC? It's optional, it might not be in there. Crack open the box and see what you've got.

If you hit F2 to go into the BIOS, you can also see what's configured there. I suppose it could be physically present but disabled in the BIOS.

As you found - the BIOS was configured to not use the RAID adapter. Once you enabled it, you see the option to get into the SCSI BIOS or config.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thats correct. Pasting link to documentation for reference [User Guide for DELL PowerEdge 2850](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-2850_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf) (PDF) Page 18